CustomTabbarViewController: Creating and Managing a Customized Tab Bar Interface with Dynamic Circle Highlighting
"CustomTabbarViewController" is a custom subclass of UITabBarController designed to provide a tailored and visually appealing tab bar interface within an iOS application. This view controller manages the presentation of multiple view controllers, each associated with a tab item, while offering customization options for the appearance and behavior of the tab bar.
Key features of this "CustomTabbarViewController" include:
Custom Tab Bar Appearance: The tab bar's appearance is customizable, including the background color, tint color, and corner radius.
Dynamic Circle Highlighting: A dynamic circle indicator highlights the currently selected tab item, providing visual feedback to the user. The circle animates to the selected tab's position, enhancing the user experience.
Flexible Layout Handling: The tab bar adjusts its layout to accommodate changes in the device orientation or safe area insets, ensuring a consistent and visually pleasing presentation across different devices and orientations.
import UIKit

class TabbarViewController: UITabBarController {
    
    var circle: UIView?
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let index = -(tabBar.items?.firstIndex(of: tabBar.selectedItem!)?.distance(to: 0))!
        let frame = frameForTabAtIndex(index: index)
        circle?.center.x = frame.origin.x + frame.width/2
        circle?.center.y = frame.origin.y + frame.height/2
        circle?.alpha = 1
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        
        self.setupTabBarUI()
        let numberOfItems = CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
        let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: (tabBar.frame.width / numberOfItems) - 20, height: tabBar.frame.height)
        circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabBarItemSize.height, height: tabBarItemSize.height))
        circle?.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2770082951, green: 0.5475645661, blue: 0, alpha: 0.28)
        circle?.layer.cornerRadius = circle!.frame.width/2
        circle?.alpha = 0
        tabBar.addSubview(circle!)
        tabBar.sendSubviewToBack(circle!)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.setupCustomTabBarFrame()
    }
    
}

extension TabbarViewController {
    // MARK: Private methods
    
    private func setupCustomTabBarFrame() {
        let height = self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom + 64
        
        var tabFrame = self.tabBar.frame
        tabFrame.size.height = height
        tabFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - height
        
        self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame
        self.tabBar.setNeedsLayout()
        self.tabBar.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    
    private func setupTabBarUI() {
        // Setup your colors and corner radius
        self.tabBar.layer.cornerRadius = 22
        self.tabBar.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.tabBar.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
        self.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 245, green: 246, blue: 247, alpha: 1)
        self.tabBar.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4670000076, green: 0.6430000067, blue: 0.3919999897, alpha: 1)
        //            self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.green
        
        // Remove the line
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let appearance = self.tabBar.standardAppearance
            appearance.shadowImage = nil
            appearance.shadowColor = nil
            self.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        } else {
            self.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
            self.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        }
    }
    
    func frameForTabAtIndex(index: Int) -> CGRect {
        var frames = tabBar.subviews.compactMap { (view:UIView) -> CGRect? in
            if let view = view as? UIControl {
                for item in view.subviews {
                    if let image = item as? UIImageView {
                        return image.superview!.convert(image.frame, to: tabBar)
                    }
                }
                return view.frame
            }
            return nil
        }
        frames.sort { $0.origin.x < $1.origin.x }
        if frames.count > index {
            return frames[index]
        }
        return frames.last ?? CGRect.zero
    }
    
    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        let index = -(tabBar.items?.firstIndex(of: item)?.distance(to: 0))!
        let frame = frameForTabAtIndex(index: index)
        self.circle?.center.x = frame.origin.x + frame.width/2
        self.circle?.center.y = frame.origin.y + frame.height/2
    }
}


